# Stat Mech Question: Finding Probability distribution from a pretty two term generating function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

So, I'll state my question first, with such a pretty generating function I would expect a cleaner probability distribution function than the one that I found, but maybe I am incorrect to expect this? Would love any feedback.

**Find the probability distribution with the generating function
\begin{equation}
    W(k) = -\frac{k^2d^2}{2} + \frac{(-ik)^4d^4\lambda}{4!}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda<<1$.  Writing $\rho(x) = \rho_0(x) + \lambda \rho_1(x) + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)$, obtain $\rho_0$ and $\rho_1$.**

What I have --- To find the probability distribution from the generating function, first from $\tilde{\rho}(k) = e^{W(k)}$

\begin{equation}
    \tilde{\rho}(k) = exp \left(-\frac{k^2d^2}{2} + \frac{(-ik)^4d^4\lambda}{4!}\right)
\end{equation}

The inverse Fourier transform $\tilde{\rho}$(k).

\begin{equation}
    \rho(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\tilde{\rho}(k)e^{ikx}dk
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \rho(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty exp \left(-\frac{k^2d^2}{2} + \frac{(-ik)^4d^4\lambda}{4!}+ ikx \right)dk
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \rho(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty exp \left(\frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4 -\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 + ikx \right)dk
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \rho(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^ {\left(\frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4\right)}e^{\left(-\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 \right)} e^{\left(ikx \right)dk}  
\end{equation}

using the expansion $ e^x =1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ... $

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \rho(x) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty 
    \left[1 + \left(\frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4\right) + \frac{\left(\frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4\right)^2}{2!} + ...\right] \cdot \left[e^{\left(-\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 \right)}\right] \cdot \left[1 + \left(ikx \right)+\frac{\left(ikx \right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(ikx \right)^3}{3!}+... \right] dk
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Organizing by powers of $\lambda$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \rho(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)\right) \cdot \left[e^{\left(-\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 \right)}\right] \cdot \left[1 + \left(ikx \right)+\frac{\left(ikx \right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(ikx \right)^3}{3!}+... \right] dk
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The odd powers in k integrated over an even integral won't contribute so you are left with

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \rho(x) &=  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)\right) \left[e^{\left(-\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 \right)}\right] \cdot \left[1 + \frac{\left(ikx \right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(ikx \right)^4}{4!} + \frac{\left(ikx \right)^6}{6!}+... \right] dk \\
    & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)\right) \left[e^{\left(-\frac{d^2}{2}k^2 \right)}\right] \cdot \left[1 - \frac{\left(kx \right)^2}{2!}+\frac{\left(kx \right)^4}{4!} - \frac{\left(kx \right)^6}{6!}+... \right] dk \\
    & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}k^4 + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)\right) e^{-\frac{d^2k^2}{2}} \cos(kx)  dk \\
    & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{d^2k^2}{2}} \cos(kx) dk
    + \frac{d^4\lambda}{4!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty k^4e^{-\frac{d^2k^2}{2}} \cos(kx) dk + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

With some help from Mathematica,

\begin{equation}
    \rho(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|d|}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2d^2}} + \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|d|^5 4!}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2d^2}}\left(3d^4-6d^2x^2 + x^4 \right) \lambda + \mathcal{O}(\lambda^2)
\end{equation}

Thus

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \rho_0(x) &= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|d|}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2d^2}} \\
        \rho_1(x) &= \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{|d|^5 4!}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2d^2}}\left(3d^4-6d^2x^2 + x^4 \right)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: I didn't check the calculations but at a high level your logic seems ok. I'm not sure why you expect the answer to look qualitatively simpler though. To zeroth order you get a Gaussian, which is pretty much the simplest thing you can get and just happens because the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian. To first order, you get a Gaussian times a polynomial, which to me seems like only a small extra complication from a Gaussian, and also is the only thing you could get given the form of your first order integral for $\rho(x)$.

Comment: The underlying issue is that the Fourier transform of $e^{-x^2}$ can be expressed in terms of elementary functions, but $e^{-x^2-x^4}$ cannot. Even if the log of the integrand is simple, the integral need not be.

Comment: Makes sense!  Thank you Andrew!